# Best way to handle no-blocking socket service result

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming

I want to talk with a proxy soft, here is [official socket example](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks/wiki/Manage-Multiple-Users).

This soft would send traffic statistic to connected cli every 10 seconds. I also need to send commands and get command results on same connection.

It cost me some time to figure out that I can't create two socket clients and connect to same server to get different results.

**My problem:**  how do I manage user config while recording traffic statistic ?

### Test:

When add a port, would get `ok` after several `cli.recv(1506)` (because the stat send every 10 second, it I don't read all the time, `ok` would behind of many `stat`) :

```
>>> cli.send(b'add: {"server_port":8003, "password":"123123"}')
46

>>>  print(cli.recv(1506))
stat: {"8002":164}

>>> print(cli.recv(1506))
stat: {"8002":336}

>>> print(cli.recv(1506))
ok

>>> print(cli.recv(1506))
stat: {"8002":31}

>>> print(cli.recv(1506))
# hang here wait for next result
```

So if I send many command, I can't recognise the which result map which command.

---

### The solution I came up with is:

```
# client main code

while True:
    # need open another sock port to recieve command
    c = self.on_new_command()
    if c:
        self.cli.send(c)
        # does python socket server ensure response is FIFO when `setblocking(False)`
        self.queue.append(c)

    ret = self.cli.recv(1524)

    if 'stat' in ret:
        self.record(ret)
    else :
        self.log(self.queue.pop(), ret)
```

I need open another sock port to receive command in this client, and have to write another client which sends commands to this... I just don't feel it is good.

Because it is my first time to play with socket programming, is my solution the best for this situation? Is there any better way to achieve my goal?